# Show date_created value from Twilio REST API

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I'm trying to access the value of `date_created` from the Twilio Calls list using the following code but it's not working for that object but does work for the other objects eg to, from, status, etc.
The only difference seems to be the use of the '_' underscore character which could be to do with it?

Here is my code:

```
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);

$calls = $twilio->calls
                ->read([], 20);

echo "<p>Call Records</p>";
?>
<table
<tr><th>SID</th><th>To</th><th>From</th><th>Status</th><th>Date Created</th><th>Duration</th><th>Price</th></tr>

<?php foreach ($calls as $record) {
    
    echo "<tr><td>$record->sid</td><td>$record->to</td><td>$record->from</td><td>$record->status</td><td>$record->date_created</td><td>$record->duration</td><td>$record->price</td></tr>";
 }
?>
</table>
```

I get the following fatal error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Twilio\\Exceptions\\TwilioException: Unknown property: date_created in /home/sites/6b/1/13d6aa4912/public_html/voip-test/twilio/vendor/twilio/sdk/src/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010/Account/CallInstance.php:197
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change my code within the foreach to the following:

```
    $newDate = date_format($call->startTime, 'Y-m-d');
    echo "<tr><td>$call->sid</td><td>$call->to</td><td>$call->from</td><td>$newDate</td><td>$call->status</td><td>$call->duration</td><td>$call->price</td></tr>";
```

Twilio Support confirmed I should be using `dateCreated` instead of `date_created` and then that threw another error from the returned date so I had to format it using `date_format`.

Posting in case this helps someone else in the future.